# nodejs http-proxy not forwarding put requests

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy

I've made a proxy using the http-proxy and express middlewares. However, it isn't forwarding PUT requests - which are essential for the application I'm proxying to. What am I doing wrong?

(The purpose of the proxy server is to provide authentication for the app behind the proxy. If there is another way to do this, I'd be grateful to know.)

```
var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.session({secret: 'rupert'}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(function(req, res) {
proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8080
});
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../public'));
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', { user: req.user, message: req.flash('error') });
});

app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/')
});

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  return next();
});

app.listen(3000,'localhost');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reverse proxy client POST & PUT requests using node-http-proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120208/how-to-reverse-proxy-client-post-put-requests-using-node-http-proxy)

Comment: I tried that - it didn't work; the time delay doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using http-proxy's buffer function, as written here: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/180

Alternatively, there could be an issue with express doing non-standard things to the request object: See issue#153 at https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/153

specifically this response from Marak:
"This is an express problem.

The Connect / Express middlewares are doing non-standard things to your response object, breaks streaming. Try using the raw request module instead of http-proxy.

If you need proper middleware stack, check out https://github.com/flatiron/union"

No idea if union will fix this, but it seems that express alters the request beyond what http-proxy can handle.